# select slide in powerpoint by hotkey when not in presentation mode

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Is there a way to change slides by hotkey when in edit mode?  I find my self switching to presentation mode, typing the number of the slide, hitting enter, and then exiting the presentation just to switch to a particular slide.  Anyone know how to do the same from edit/normal mode without using the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in PowerPoint to jump to a specific slide in Edit Mode. That is only available in Slide Show mode (in Slide Show mode press slide number and then hit the Enter key).

If it helps you can try using the Slide Sorter View from the bottom right corner. And if you want to do it without the mouse there are some shortcut key combination:

```
Alt+V, then press D
```

or

```
Alt+W, then press I (this will change to TAB)
```

Comment: Great tips, thank you!  Looks about tied with launching presentation mode (F5), typing the slide number and hitting Enter, then exiting presentation mode (esc).  But something nicer about staying in non-presentation mode.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

[image: explanation]

If you don't want to click the link here's what it says

When in a text box, just hit esc to get out of text input mode, esc again to deselect a box, and then up/down arrows or home/end to navigate your slides. If you're using a bunch of slides, I don't know the command to search.

Comment: Yes on the edit mode, but looking for a way to go to a particular slide, like slide #27, without having to hit the down arrow key 26 times or scroll with the mouse.

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is using the Alt command. When viewing a slide press, in this order (separately) alt -> r -> i                                                  That will show you the slide viewer... I don't think it's really what you're looking for though :(

Comment: Oh bahaha, the guy above me already said that. Ignore this.